# Measure area inside of image - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html

Situation:
Got png (or bmp) image inside html file, on image there are black rectangles on white background. Image size is always constant AxB, rectangles are not rotated and are different each time. Html file and images are generated automatically by some software as a job report.

I need to measure area (in square pixels) of that rectangle i point and click with mouse.

I imagine it this way:
Image is loaded into array or something, when i click image, desired function perform following tasks:

- find nearest black pixels to the left, right, up and down, (searching through array from coordinates i click with cursor)
- calculate size of rectangle (based on those black pixels),
- calculate area,
- return area to some variable.

Now, is it even possible? Is there maybe another method? I'm thinking about js solution since i'm not familiar with jquery at all; php and server-side solutions are not an option since the html files are standalone files on local drive.

Thank you in advance

----------------edit-------------

Images to process are black&white (always 1bit!) and look like here.
http://www.dropbox.com/s/smh4982om3hkhd8/job_report_image1.png

I know that first rectangle marked with red "1." has size of 542x570px (inside) - so area is 308940 square pixels - i measured it with MS Paint ;) - now i want to achieve the same in browser - click inside this rectangle and get the same result.

Comment: http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2009/05/png-parser-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an implementation but more a way to go with javascript and HTML5:
Import your image in a 2d canvas context
get the coordinates in the canvas where the mouse click occured
then using canvas getImageData and go through them to get surrounding black pixel

more info on getImageData here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand true, you want to calculate area of an image.
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/osmanraif/xLBdP/3/) is a working sample. If you need to calculate with borders you should use   myitem.clientHeight * myitem.clientWidth else myitem.offsetWidth*myitem.offsetHeight

```
function calculate(myitem) {
alert(myitem.clientHeight * myitem.clientWidth);
alert(myitem.offsetWidth*myitem.offsetHeight)
```

}

Comment: No, no - area of rectangle (drawed) inside the image, not the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

This might be little useful for you to find the area: (using php)

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatefrompng('http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/5673/rotatetrans.png');//open the image
$w = imagesx($img);//the width
$h = imagesy($img);//the height



//Convert to centimeter
    $dpi = 300;
    $h = $h * 2.54 / $dpi;
    $w = $w * 2.54 / $dpi;

echo "width is:".$w;



echo "Height is:".$h;

$area = $w * $h;
echo "Area is:".$area;
?>
```

Edit:

The number of pixels in an image is simply the height multiplied by the width.

1. [Demo Here>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/n6Z1vs)

Comment: Interesting - but i don't need convert results to [cm], pixels are enough, also i cannot run php. 
Looking at your example picture - can you tell me "how many yellow pixels are there inside 'smiley'"? (I need that information)

Comment: If you don't need an answer in [cm], then remove "conversion to cm" part from the above code..

Comment: As i uderstand the code - its just a width and height of whole image. I've just added additional explanations to myy question above.